# Sending 'this' to js function from file upload element

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an image upload. onClick of one visible button, it triggers the hidden input form (it is hidden because it is ugly), which asks user to pick a file. When the choice is made, it triggers `onChange="imagePreview(this);"` function, which then works with 'this' element.

```
function imagePreview (this) {
   var files = this.files;
   var file = files[0];
   ...
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get rid of the insertion of `onChange="imagePreview(this);"` in the html element, so I need to somehow call this element from the javascript or jQuery. Can someone give me a hint on that.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the element and use **addEventListener**, or jQuery's **.change** method to set the event listener

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="myfile" />
```

JS

```
function imagePreview(){
   //The context of the function will
   //be the element that triggered it
   var files = this.files;
   var file = files[0];    
}

var fileCtrl = document.getElementById("myfile");
fileCtrl.addEventListener("change",imagePreview);
//jQuery
$("#myfile").change(imagePreview);
```

[**jQuery .change**](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

[**addEventListener**](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can attach event listener via jQuery,

```
$(function() {
    $("that.input").change(imagePreview); 
    //this will send this as parameter to imagePreview function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass `this` parameter in the function else it will point to the `window`

```
function imagePreview (elem) {
   var files = elem.files;
   var file = files[0];
   ...
}
```

Now, use `this` where you bind the event:

```
onChange="imagePreview(this)"
```

Comment: what's the OP wanted exactly?

Comment: To get rid of the onchange attribute in the html